# Setting cookie using header("Set-cookie") vs setcookie() function

Tags: php, cookies

I'm refactoring some code and found something I've never seen. the function is used for user to set cookie when user logs in:

```
  function setUserCookie($name, $value) {
     $date = date("D, d M Y H:i:s",strtotime('1 January 2015')) . 'GMT';
     header("Set-Cookie: {$name}={$value}; EXPIRES{$date};");
  }
```

now that I've been assigned to refactor code I'm planning to use `setcookie` function which essentially does same thing according to php.net.

My question is: is there any difference between two and which one should I use?

NOTE: this code was written long time ago so I'm assuming that at that time `setcookie` didnt exist?

Comment: You might find [`new Cookie($name)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L51) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie). So that's a third option for setting cookies. Honestly, never set the HTTP header directly. Use the built-in PHP function or the constructor cited here in order to set cookies with properly escaped values using header values that are built automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no good reason not to use setcookie. The above code doesn't properly encode names and values, so that's at least one major benefit to refactoring.

Comment: setcookie() doesn't pass 2038 on 32-bit systems.  It's an issue for web servers on embedded platforms (they won't be updated).

Comment: `setcookie()` does not have a Psr-7 equivalent without using a compatibility package.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two functions is that `header()` is the general function for setting HTTP headers while `setcookie()` is specifically meant to set the `Set-Cookie` header.

`header()` therefore takes a string containing the complete header, while `setcookie()` takes several cookie-specific arguments and then creates the `Set-Cookie` header from them.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a use case in which you can't use setcookie

- you run a website on PHP<7.3
- you have to set 'SameSite' cookie attribute

You can achieve that by exploiting a bug in setcookie, but I wouldn't rely on a bug as it gets fixed over time: `setcookie('samesite-test', '1', 0, '/; samesite=strict');`

Or you can use PHP **header** function: `header("Set-Cookie: samesite-test=1; expires=0; path=/; samesite=Strict");`

Note that **secure** option is required when setting **samesite** attribute

Comment: Well done. This is exactly what I was looking for my PHP 5.5+server. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

One big difference is, that setcookie always sets host_only=false and there is nothing you can do about it.

So if you have to set host_only=true for whatever reasons you have to use the header method. As far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I replicated what I believe to be the exact behavior of  `setCookie` programmatically. Here is my implementation, if it can be useful for anyone else.

```php
function setUserCookie($name, $value, $expires = 0, $path = "", $domain = "", $secure = false, $http_only = false) {
   $value = rawurlencode($value);
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
   $date = date("D, d-M-Y H:i:s",$expires) . ' GMT';
   $header = "Set-Cookie: {$name}={$value}";
   if($expires != 0) {
     $header .= "; expires={$date}; Max-Age=".($expires - time());
   }
   if($path != "") {
     $header .= "; path=".$path;
   }
   if($domain != "") {
     $header .= "; domain=".$domain;
   }
   if($secure) {
     $header .= "; secure";
   }
   if($http_only) {
     $header .= "; HttpOnly";
   }
   header($header, false);
}
```

The difference with your function are exactly the difference with `setCookie` (more arguments like custom expires, path, domain, secure and httpOnly). Especially, note the second argument to "header" (`false`) so that it becomes possible to place multiple cookies with different calls to the function.