# Remove duplicate "Set-Cookie" header from PHP response

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers, setcookie, response-headers

This is an example script from a larger application, but shows the general process of what I'm trying to do.  If I have the following script:

```
<?php
ob_start();

setcookie('test1', 'first');
setcookie('test1', 'second');
setcookie('test1', 'third');
setcookie('test2', 'keep');

//TODO remove duplicate test1 from headers

ob_end_clean();
die('end test');
```

I get the following response (as viewed via Fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 21:54:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Set-Cookie: test1=first
Set-Cookie: test1=second
Set-Cookie: test1=third
Set-Cookie: test2=keep
Content-Length: 8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

end test
```

The problem is that `Set-Cookie: test1`... exists 3 different times, therefore increasing the header size unnecessarily. (Again, this is a simplified example -
 in reality, I'm dealing with ~10 duplicate cookies in the ~800-byte range.)

**Is there anything I can write in place of the `TODO` that would get rid of the header either completely or so it only shows once?** i.e. the following is my end goal:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 21:54:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Set-Cookie: test1=third
Set-Cookie: test2=keep
Content-Length: 8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

end test
```

though the `Set-Cookie: test1=third` could not exist too and that's fine, but `Set-Cookie: test2=keep` needs to remain.  When I try `setcookie('test1', '', 1);` to delete the cookie, it adds an additional header to mark it as expired:

```
Set-Cookie: test1=first
Set-Cookie: test1=second
Set-Cookie: test1=third
Set-Cookie: test2=keep
Set-Cookie: test1=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0
```

And if I try removing the header like:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    foreach (headers_list() as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie: test1') !== false) {
            header_remove('Set-Cookie');
        }
    }
}
```

it removes all `Set-Cookie` headers when I only want `test1` removed.

Comment: Could you store the headers in an array? e.g. if you had a View class, that could have a (static?) method _SetCookie()_ which would store the key and value in an associative array. Then when sending the final headers, just iterate over that associative array and call _setcookie()_, which would only get called once per key...

Comment: I wish!  Ideally that's how this would be set up, but by the time it gets to my script the `Set-Cookie: test1=...` has already been run multiple times, so the place I can inject any sort of code is at the `TODO`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggested in that last block of code, the [`headers_list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) function could be used to check what headers have been sent. Using that, the last values for each cookie could be stored in an associative array. The names and values can be extracted using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) (along with [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim)).

When multiple cookies with the same name have been detected, we can use the [`header_remove()`](http://php.net/header_remove) call like you had, but then set the cookies to the final values. See the example below, as well as [this example phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tu4g-k1c7).

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    $cookiesSet = []; //associative array to store the last value for each cookie
    $rectifyCookies = false; //multiple values detected for same cookie name

    foreach (headers_list() as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') !== false) {
            list($setCookie, $cookieValue) = explode(':', $header);
            list($cookieName, $cookieValue) = explode('=', trim($cookieValue));
            if (array_key_exists($cookieName, $cookiesSet)) {
                $rectifyCookies = true;
            }
            $cookiesSet[$cookieName] = $cookieValue;
        }
    }
    if ($rectifyCookies) {
        header_remove('Set-Cookie');
        foreach($cookiesSet as $cookieName => $cookieValue) {
            //might need to consider optional 3rd - 8th parameters 
            setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

> **Cache-Control** max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
> **Connection**  keep-alive
> **Content-Encoding** gzip
> **Content-Type** text/html; charset=utf-8
> **Date** Wed, 26 Apr 2017 15:31:33 GMT
> **Expires** Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
> **Pragma** no-cache
> **Server**  nginx
> **Set-Cookie**  test1=third
>                      test2=keep
> **Transfer-Encoding** chunked
> **Vary**    Accept-Encoding

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is excellent. I would recommend changing two things to properly handle additional cookie header params. 1) change **both** explodes to limit at 2 Example: `explode(':', $header, 2)` 
2) Use the `header()` function rather than `setcookie()` like `header("Set-Cookie: {$cookieName}={$cookieValue}", false);`
These changes will maintain any expires, Max-Age, etc params from the original Set-Cookie headers.

Comment: @Stenerson okay I am fine with adding the third parameter to the call to `explode()` but after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972219/1575353) don't see much of a reason not to use `setcookie()` (unless [the 32-bit 2038 overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/1575353) affects you)....

Comment: Note this code could be put into a function and registered with [`header-register_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-register-callback.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you think that the cookie removing code you showed us would remove the setcookie for test2.

If your code is setting the same cookie multiple times then you need to change your code so it stops setting the cookie multiple times! Anything else is a sloppy workaround.

Comment: You mean `header_remove('Set-Cookie');`? The way it's defined (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php), it removes all `Set-Cookie` headers. So regardless of the cookie name, it clears them all.  I'm working with a framework that seems to be adding the cookie multiple times, so I'm just trying to clean that up before the response is returned without hacking the core.

Comment: Doh, of course! Leaving aside the fact its the wrong way to fix the problem, you could just parse the setcookie headers into an array of name=>value, then header_remove('Set-Cookie') then iterate through your array again. But this then leads to a slightly less bad solution of just populating the array in the first place and not calling setcookie() until the data is marshalled (but its still the wrong solution)